# Fire vue method from jquery on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to append a click event to an already existing dom element.

```
<div class="logMe" data-log-id="{{ data.log }}"></div>
...
<div id="events"></div>
```

I can't seem to access outside vue methods within my jquery click handler. It will throw `logData is not defined`.

```
new Vue({
   el: '#events',
   mounted() {
      $('.logMe').on('click', function() {
           const data = $(this).data('log-id');
           this.logData(data); // throws logData is not defined
      });
   },
   methods: {
      logData(id) {
         console.log(id); // never fires
         ... hit server
      },
   },
});
```

If anyone knows of a better way to append click events to `.html` elements that would be great! But how can I bubble up and find my vue methods? [Here's a fiddle to illustrate](https://jsfiddle.net/pu8pp62v/82/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: "logData(id) {" ... does not look like a valid syntax to me?

Comment: @axel.michel updated `methods: {}`

Comment: I assume `{{data.log}}` is set by something other than Vue?

Comment: @Bert yep server rendered by a django template. I just want to append click events via vue. Not sure if possible :\

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get your code working you would write it like this:

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
   el: '#events',
   mounted() {
      $('.logMe').on('click', (evt) => {
        console.log("called")
           const data = $(evt.target).data('logId');
           this.logData(data); 
      });
   },
   methods: {
      logData(id) {
         console.log(id);
      },
   },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div class="logMe" data-log-id="10">Something</div>
<div id="events"></div>
```

Note that the code uses an arrow function to define the click handler so that the appropriate `this` is captured to call the `logData` method on the Vue. However, doing that means you lose the `this` you want to get the data from the data property, so instead the example uses `evt.target`.

There is an alternative approach where you capture the Vue in a variable and call the method directly from your jQuery event.

```js
console.clear()

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#events',
   methods: {
      logData(id) {
         console.log(id); // never fires
      },
   },
});

$('.logMe').on('click', function(){
  app.logData($(this).data("logId"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logMe" data-log-id="10">Something</div>
<div id="events"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Much easier solution =

```
window.app = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   methods: {
      myMethod(data) { ... }
   }
}

// jQuery
window.app.myMethod(data);
```